# Get method not supported, use post

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the error when I try to create a post and I don't know how to fix it since I just began using laravel and I'm still a noobie.

Route (**web.php**)

```
Route::put('/create_action', [App\Http\Controllers\ActionController::class, 'createAction'])->name('auditor.create_action');
```

**This is my controller method**:

```
  public function createAction(Request $request) {

    $sectors = \DB::table('sector')->get();
    $risicosoorten = \DB::table('risicosoort')->get();
    $risicoclassificaties = \DB::table('risicoclassificatie')->get();
    $users = \DB::table('users')->where('name')->get();
    $statussen = \DB::table('status')->get();

    return view('auditor.create_action' , [
        'sectors' => $sectors,
        'risicosoorten' => $risicosoorten,
        'risicoclassificaties' => $risicoclassificaties,
        'users' => $users,
        'statussen' => $statussen
    ]);


$actie->create([

'create_date' => $req->create_date,
'bron_detail' => $req->bron_detail,
'audit_oordel' => $req->audit_oordel, 
'process' => $req->process, 
'nummer_bevinding' => $req->nummer_bevinding, 
'omschrijving_bevinding' => $req->omschrijving_bevinding, 
'probleem' => $req->probleem, 
'risico_beschrijving' => $req->risico_beschrijving, 
'oorzaak' => $req->oorzaak, 
'aanbeveling_ia' => $req->aanbeveling_ia, 
'map' => $req->map, 
'datum_deadline' => $req->datum_deadline, 
'datum_bijgesteld' => $req->datum_bijgesteld, 
'datum_gesloten' => $req->datum_gesloten, 
'voortgang' => $req->voortgang, 
'aantekeningen_ia' => $req->aantekeningen_ia, 
'oordeel_ia' => $req->oordeel_ia, 
'sector' => $req->sector, 
'pr' => $req->pr, 
'sr' => $req->sr, 
'arc' => $req->arc, 
'orc' => $req->orc, 
'grc' => $req->grc, 
'status' => $req->status, 
'sub_status' => $req->sub_status
]);
}
```

**my blade file with the form:**

```
@extends('layouts.master')


@section('title')
    
@endsection

@section('content')
    
<div class="create_action" id="post">
    <form action="{{ route('auditor.create_action') }}" method="POST">
     @method('PUT')
      @csrf
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="creation_date">Datum ontstaan actie</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="create_date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bron_detail">Bron detail</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bron_detail">
        </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitBtn" value="submitPost"><strong>Maak actie aan</strong></button>
@endsection
```

and wayy more form input fields but trying to keep it as short as possible!

[image: laravel error]

Comment: As well as 2 opening `<form>` tags, you have no closing `</form>`.

Comment: Note also that your `createAction()` method returns a view *before* doing the `create()`.  The `create()` will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have two opening form tags in your view. Right after the @csrf directive. Is this intentional? Because you can not nest form tags.

This may be what is causing your error because the application is trying to use the 'Get' method for the inner form tag since no method was stated.

Comment: i've removed it and it doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eUL8.png

sorry couldn't add it to the post due low rep

Comment: Are you trying to create a new record? Try changing Route::put() to Route::post() and remove the method('PUT') in your blade file.

Comment: I am trying to create a new record yes, sadly it still didn't fix it :(

Comment: Are you using vagrant? If so try restarting vagrant. Then use the actual route in the form instead of the route name. i.e <form action="{{ url('/create_action') }}" method="POST">